# Calling stored procedure from another stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have 3 insert stored procedures each SP inserts data in 2 different tables

```
Table 1          Table 2                
idPerson         idProduct             
name             productName            
phoneNumber      productdescription     
FK-idProduct
```

SP for table 1                            SP for table 2

```
create procedure test1                create procedure test2
WITH                                  WITH 
EXECUTE as caller                     EXECUTE as caller
AS                                    AS
declare                               declare

@idPerson int,                        @idProduct int,
@name varchar(20),                    @productName varchar(50),
@phone varchar(20)                    @productoDescription varchar(50)


  SET nocount on;                     SET nocount on;
    Begin                             Begin
      insert into table1(                insert into table2(
                idPerson,                          idProduct,
                name,                              productName,
                phone)                             productDescription)
          values(                            values(
                @idPerson,                         @idProduct,
                @name,                             @productName,
                @phone)                            @productDescription)
      end                               end
```

I need to call stored procedure test 2 from stored procedure test 1 and insert the FK-ID in the table 1

Answer (score 48):

Simply call `test2` from `test1` like:

```
EXEC test2 @newId, @prod, @desc;
```

Make sure to get `@id` using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), which gets the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope:

```
SELECT @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: will it do the insert of idPerson, name, phone and idProduct in table1 and idProduct, productName and productDescription in table 2?

Comment: @@SCOPE_IDENTITY isn't a thing. Use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: is this possible if my other stored proc is in another database

Comment: I would use IDENT_CURRENT('TableName') to get the most recent Id entered into a specific table.

Answer (score 10):

You could add an OUTPUT parameter to test2, and set it to the new id straight after the INSERT using:

```
SELECT @NewIdOutputParam = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Then in test1, retrieve it like so:

```
DECLARE @NewId INTEGER
EXECUTE test2 @NewId OUTPUT
-- Now use @NewId as needed
```

Comment: Beware that SCOPE_IDENTITY() can't be relied on to return accurate results unless you use MAX_DOP=1 on SQL versions before 2012. (See here: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/)

Comment: `connect.microsoft.com` no-longer exists, but the issue described in the comment above is documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-may-receive-incorrect-values-when-using-scope-identity-and-identity-ba9b17b0-338f-5f88-2c48-783e72e0034e - apparently this is fixed in SQL Server 2008 R2 **SP1** and later (so you don't need to upgrade to 2012 or later just for this).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `table2`'s idProduct is an identity, you cannot insert it explicitly until you set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on that table

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table2 ON;
```

before the insert.

So one of two, you modify your second stored and call it with only the parameters `productName` and `productDescription` and then get the new ID

```
EXEC test2 'productName', 'productDescription'
SET @newID = SCOPE_IDENTIY()
```

or you already have the ID of the product and you don't need to call `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and can make the insert on `table1` with that ID