# Execute a stored procedure in another stored procedure in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can i execute a stored procedure in another stored procedure in SQL server? 
How will I pass the parameters of the second procedure.?

Comment: Are you planning to do this in C# or as a StoredProc on the Server itself?

Comment: use the `exec` keyword.

Comment: I need to execute in Server itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858620/calling-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure-sql-server

Answer (score 47):

If you only want to perform some specific operations by your second SP and do not require values back from the SP then simply do:

```
Exec secondSPName  @anyparams
```

Else, if you need values returned by your second SP inside your first one, then create a temporary table variable with equal numbers of columns and with same definition of column return by second SP. Then you can get these values in first SP as:

```
Insert into @tep_table
Exec secondSPName @anyparams
```

**Update:**

To pass parameter to second sp, do this:

```
Declare @id ID_Column_datatype 
Set @id=(Select id from table_1 Where yourconditions)

Exec secondSPName @id
```

**Update 2:**

Suppose your second sp returns `Id` and `Name` where type of `id` is `int` and `name` is of `varchar(64)` type.

now, if you want to select these values in first sp then create a temporary `table` variable and insert values into it:

```
Declare @tep_table table
(
  Id int,
  Name varchar(64)
)
Insert into @tep_table
Exec secondSP

Select * From @tep_table
```

This will return you the values returned by second SP.

Hope, this clear all your doubts.

Comment: tanx.. ya i need values returned by second sp inside the first one. bt the parameter which i need to pass is an output of first procedure. is it possible.? Pls see this example. SP1 Select id from table_1. is it possible to pass this id as the parameter of the second procedure.?

Comment: Yes this is posible but first you need to store this id into a variable and then pass the same to second sp. See updated answer.

Comment: The above steps worked.tanx. How can i get the output value of second Sp from the first one..?

Comment: This is already answered. anyway, see updated answer again for more explaination.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you have one stored procedure like this

First stored procedure:

```
Create  PROCEDURE LoginId
     @UserName nvarchar(200),
     @Password nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @loginID  int

    SELECT @loginID = LoginId 
    FROM UserLogin 
    WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Password = @Password

    return @loginID
END
```

Now you want to call this procedure from another stored procedure like as below

Second stored procedure

```
Create  PROCEDURE Emprecord
         @UserName nvarchar(200),
         @Password nvarchar(200),
         @Email nvarchar(200),
         @IsAdmin bit,
         @EmpName nvarchar(200),
         @EmpLastName nvarchar(200),
         @EmpAddress nvarchar(200),
         @EmpContactNo nvarchar(150),
         @EmpCompanyName nvarchar(200)

    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO UserLogin VALUES(@UserName,@Password,@Email,@IsAdmin)

        DECLARE @EmpLoginid int

        **exec @EmpLoginid= LoginId @UserName,@Password**

        INSERT INTO tblEmployee VALUES(@EmpName,@EmpLastName,@EmpAddress,@EmpContactNo,@EmpCompanyName,@EmpLoginid)
    END
```

As you seen above, we can call one stored procedure from another

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that like this:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Results TABLE (Tid INT PRIMARY KEY);

   INSERT @Results

   EXEC Procedure2 [parameters];
   SET @total 1;

END
SELECT @total
```

Answer (score 2):

Your **sp_test**: Return fullname

```
USE [MY_DB]
GO

IF (OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[sp_test]', 'P') IS NOT NULL)
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_test;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_test 
@name VARCHAR(20),
@last_name VARCHAR(30),
@full_name VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS

SET @full_name = @name + @last_name;

GO
```

In your **sp_main**

```
...
DECLARE @my_name VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @my_last_name VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE @my_full_name VARCHAR(50);
...

EXEC sp_test @my_name, @my_last_name, @my_full_name OUTPUT;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call User-defined Functions in a stored procedure alternately

this may solve your problem to call stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,
Its easy to way we call the function inside the store procedure.

for e.g. create user define Age function and use in select query.

```
select dbo.GetRegAge(R.DateOfBirth, r.RegistrationDate) as Age,R.DateOfBirth,r.RegistrationDate from T_Registration R
```

Answer (score 0):

**Procedure example:**

```
Create  PROCEDURE SP_Name
     @UserName nvarchar(200),
     @Password nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @loginID  int

    --Statements for this Store Proc
  --
  -- 
  --

  --execute second store procedure
  --below line calling sencond Store Procedure Exec is used for execute Store Procedure.
    **Exec SP_Name_2 @params** (if any) 


END
```