# Calling a stored procedure (A) from stored procedure (B) and using the result set form A in B

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms-2012

In SQL server 2012 I am looking for a way to call a Stored Procedure (A) from stored Procedure (B).  SP A returns a result set that I then will need to use in SP B.
Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802511/execute-a-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

yes, with multiple columns too:

```
create table tablea
(
     cola int,
     colb varchar(50) NULL
)

GO
insert into tablea(cola, colb) values (1, 'test')
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_A
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT cola, colb from tablea
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_B
AS
BEGIN

 Declare @TempTable Table (col1 int, col2 varchar(50) NULL)

 Insert @TempTable Exec sp_A

 SELECT * from @TempTable

END

GO

exec sp_B
```

Comment: I need to return a result set to b that has multiple rows that need to be used in B

Comment: @TimBrown ok, the above will work with multiple columns.

Comment: I am still getting the error 'An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.'

Comment: ok, it looks like you are doing a number of insert execs in your stored procedure chain - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795263/errors-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-and-cannot-use-the-rollback-s

Comment: I think you should look at creating a table and inserting and selecting from that table in your different procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp table / table variable / real table and insert the results into it.

```
Insert Into MyTable
EXEC MySP
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."

Comment: I use this all the time without any issues. Are you only returning results for 1 table using something like `SELECT * FROM {Table}`? Or are you using a RETURN ?? statement in your SP (A)?