# Execute sp_setapprole in another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any possibility or workaround to execute sp_setapprole in a stored procedure? I read its not possible but maybe someone knows a workaround?

Comment: Refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802511/execute-a-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Comment: One workaround is to avoid application roles. But we cannot suggest alternatives without know what you are trying to accomplish.